# How to get django's unittest TestLoader to find and run my doctests?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, doctest

In Django, my tests are a set of `test_foo.py` files inside `my_django_app/tests/`, which each contain a `TestCase` subclass, and which django automatically finds and runs.

I have a bunch of utility modules with simple doctests that I would like to be included with my test suite. I tried using `doctest.DocTestSuite()` to define test suites in `my_django_app/tests/test_doctests.py`, but django's test runner does not find the new tests in that module.

Is there a way I can create a TestCase class that calls my doctests, or somehow otherwise define a new `tests/test_foo.py` module that would run these tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a new module, `my_django_app/tests/test_doctests.py`, that looks like:

```
import doctest
import unittest

# These are my modules that contain doctests:
from util import bitwise
from util import text
from util import urlutil
DOCTEST_MODULES = (
  bitwise,
  text,
  urlutil,
)

# unittest.TestLoader will call this when it finds this module:
def load_tests(*args, **kwargs):
  test_all_doctests = unittest.TestSuite()
  for m in DOCTEST_MODULES:
    test_all_doctests.addTest(doctest.DocTestSuite(m))
  return test_all_doctests
```

Django uses the builtin unittest [TestLoader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.discover), which, during test discovery, will call load_tests() on your test module. So we define `load_tests` which creates a test suite out of all of the doctests.

Answer (score 2):

The automagic of Django `unittests` discovery looks for a `load_tests` function in your test_foo module and will run it. So you can use that to add your doctests to the test suite ...

```
import doctest
import module_with_doctests

def load_tests(loader, tests, ignore):
    tests.addTests(doctest.DocTestSuite(module_with_doctests))
    return tests
```

Also, due to a bug(?) in `unittest` your `load_tests` function won't be run unless your `test_foo` module also defines a `TestCase`-derived class like so:

```
class DoNothingTest(TestCase):
    """Encourage Django unittests to run `load_tests()`."""
    def test_example(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import django.test.runner

testsuite = django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner().build_suite()
```

but, as best I can tell, basic unittest discover produces the same collection

```
import unittest

testsuite = unittest.TestLoader().discover('.')
```

---

unrelated

I did notice that unittest and django.test appear to use an internal attribute `TestCase._testMethodName` differently, in unittest, this is the testcase module+class namespace, in django, this appeared to be a random testcase method name, with the module and class being attributes of `self.__module__`. probably try to avoid needing to poke around in internals anyway though